# how to convert a column of pandas series without the header

Tags: pandas, type-conversion

It is quite odd as I hadn't experienced the issue until now,, for conversion of data series.

So I have wind speed data by date & hour at different heights, retrieved from NREL.

```
file09 = 'wind/wind_yr2009.txt'
wind09 = pd.read_csv(file09, encoding = "utf-8", names = ['DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)', 'HOUR-MST', 'AWS@20m [m/s]', 'AWS@50m [m/s]', 'AWS@80m [m/s]', 'AMPLC(2-80m)'])

file10 = 'wind/wind_yr2010.txt'
wind10 = pd.read_csv(file10, encoding = "utf-8", names = ['DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)', 'HOUR-MST', 'AWS@20m [m/s]', 'AWS@50m [m/s]', 'AWS@80m [m/s]', 'AMPLC(2-80m)'])
```

I merge the two readings of .txt files below

```
wind = pd.concat([wind09, wind10], join='inner')
```

Then drop the duplicate headings..

```
wind = wind.reset_index().drop_duplicates(keep='first').set_index('index')

print(wind['HOUR-MST'])
```

Printing would return smth like the following -

index

0       HOUR-MST

1              1

2              2

I wasn't sure at first but apparently index 0 is on HOUR-MST, which is the column heading. Python does recognize it as I can infer the column data using the specific header. Yet, when I try converting into `int`

```
temp = hcodebook.iloc[wind['HOUR-MST'].astype(int) - 1]
```

Both errors were returned, as I later tried to convert to `float`

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'HOUR-MST'
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'HOUR-MST'
```

I verified it is only the 0th index that has strings by using `try/except` in `for` loop.

I think the reason is because I didnt' use the parameter `sep` when reading these file - as that is the only difference with the previous attempts with other files where the data conversion is troubling me.

Yet it doesn't necessarily enlighten me in how to address it.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Does your csv file already have headers and you need to use skiprows=1 to avoid getting the headers from the csv file?

Comment: I used the `names` parameter in `pd.read_csv` command to replace the file's headers - would that still count as index 0?

Comment: Yes, you need to add skiprows=1 in your pd.read_csv to avoid getting that first two with column names if you're going to use names paramter.

Comment: Yes from there on I was able to figure with relatively ease, turns out `reset_index`  wasn't working correctly even. thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MCVE:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

cfile = StringIO("""A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8""")

pd.read_csv(cfile, names=['a','b','c','d'], sep='\s\s+')
```

Header included in data:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  A  B  C  D
1  1  2  3  4
2  5  6  7  8
```

Use `skiprows` to avoid getting headers:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
​
cfile = StringIO("""A  B  C  D
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8""")

pd.read_csv(cfile, names=['a','b','c','d'], sep='\s\s+', skiprows=1)
```

No headers:

```
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  3  4
1  5  6  7  8
```